# github desktop - wrong folder permissions

Tags: git, github, mamp, mamp-pro

I use github desktop. I was working on my branch and at one time I needed to upgrade my MAMP to MAMP PRO. In MAMP PRO I needed to set up new localserver with SSL. When setting up new server I needed to change access rights for directory and files. After making change my Github desktop shows all files that weren't changed as changed (in the right panel which shows changes is empty), files that were changed are not shown in git desktop and versions of files locally are old (before changes).

Git desktop is currently showing "branch A", but when I checked in terminal, it showed that currently master is shown. At one moment when I tried to change to my desired "branch A", git opened error: fatal: Unable to create '.../.git/index.lock': Permission denied
 (128)

After a little research I figured out that changing permissions have made Git desktop act strange. How to get it back with my uncommitted changes from "Branch A"?

Comment: Do the opposite of what you did before?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't remember what was starting configuration.

Comment: You should not mix users unless you know what you are doing (especially not root) as you need to know about groups and have them properly configured for this to work well.

Comment: I would suggest restoring your backup of your MAMP and simply do the upgrade again.  Then be more careful how you do things.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply try removing the lock file using git shell.

```
rm -rf .git/index.lock
```

Also please try running github for desktop with admin privileges.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would removing git lock file discard my uncommited changes? And how to run git with admin privileges?

Comment: I think it won't remove your uncommitted work. Lock files are usually used to prevent multiple applications accessing the same location at a time. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking

Comment: You can simply right click the github's windows application and chose run as administrator option